# WordPress Menu Improperly Renders to Theme Location

Tags: php, wordpress

In building a WordPress theme from the ground up, I wish to have a Main Menu appear near the top of a web page and a Footer Menu appear near the bottom of a web page. Here is how I registered the navigation menus:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
  'header-menu'     =>  'Meta Music Header Menu',
  'footer-menu'     =>  'Meta Music Footer Menu'
));
```

The Main Menu is placed in 'header.php':

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
  <div id='header-menu'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location', 'header-menu' ); ?>
  </div>
```

The Footer Menu is placed in 'footer.php':

```
<footer id='site-footer'>
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'metamusic-footer-widget' ) ?>
  <?php wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location', 'footer-menu' ); ?>
</footer>
```

As far as I can tell the custom nav menus are properly placed and registered. Naturally, they need to be styled for a more pleasing view. However, my concern here is that the placements are not reflected in the HTML rendering. The attached screenshots depict the custom menus and their HTML renderings. Note, the Main Menu at the top of the page renders as the Footer Menu.

Where am I going wrong? I checked the WordPress Codex, and my code complies.

Your feedback is appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the the problem is that you are not using the wp_nav_menu() function correctly which causes it to just display the first available none empty menu.

try:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
'menu' => 'footer-menu'
) );
```

This should call the correct menu item. You should also replace the header code with the same and cahnge the reference from footer to header to ensure the correct menu is called.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I used improper syntax. The nav menu placements should read as follows:

<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location', 'header-menu' )); ?> and <?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location', 'footer-menu' )); ?>